# Testing Library's `user-event` button click event must be called twice to get the same results as with one `fireEvent` click

Tags: react-testing-library, user-event

I have a form created with React Hook Form that has a required text input field and a submit button. If the user doesn't enter a value to the field before submitting the form, an error message (from `formState: { errors }` of RHF's `useForm` hook) is shown to the user in a `div` element that is otherwise hidden.

This code checks this functionality correctly in my test, using (React) Testing Library and its `fireEvent` function:

```js
render(<MyPage />);
const submitButton = screen.getByRole("button", { name: "Submit form" });

await act(async () => {
  fireEvent.click(submitButton);
});

const errorMessage = screen.queryByText("This value is required");
expect(errorMessage).toBeVisible();
```

However, I thought I'd start using the [@testing-library/user-event](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@testing-library/user-event) library in my tests to better simulate an actual user.

Following its documentation, I tried the following:

```js
const user = userEvent.setup();
render(<MyPage />);
const submitButton = screen.getByRole("button", { name: "Submit form" });

await user.click(submitButton);

const errorMessage = screen.queryByText("This value is required");
expect(errorMessage).toBeVisible();
```

This doesn't work, i.e. the query doesn't find any elements.

Neither does this:

```js
await act(async () => {
  user.click(submitButton);
});
```

This DOES work:

```js
await act(async () => {
  await user.click(submitButton);
});
```

but gives a warning "The current testing environment is not configured to support act".

Interestingly what works best is calling the event twice (and not wrapping it in  `act`):

```js
await user.click(submitButton);
await user.click(submitButton);
```

It seems that actually any two events make the test pass without warnings, e.g.

```js
await user.click(submitButton);
await user.tab();
```

I also have `@testing-library/jest-dom` imported in the file which I guess might cause the `act`-related warning.

So I know there are a lot of moving parts here that might cause the issue, but does anyone see any logical reason **why I have to call these `user-event` events twice to trigger the same effect that I get with a single `fireEvent` call?**

Just to be clear, the error message is shown correctly – and immediately after the button click – in the browser when I test this manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing for appearance and disappearance with React Testing Library is sometimes tricky to get the timing fully right.  I've had success waiting for the appearance of the element in similar tests with userEvent.

https://testing-library.com/docs/guide-disappearance/#2-using-waitfor

```
render(<MyPage />);
const submitButton = screen.getByRole("button", { name: "Submit form" });

userEvent.click(submitButton);

await waitFor(() => {
  expect(screen.queryByText("This value is required")).toBeVisible()
})
```

Comment: Thank you! That works without warnings (if I just add an `await` in front of the `userEvent` call also) and also feels logical in readability sense.